# How to capture the Error of RxJava SubScription flow, after it has been disposed?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have the following code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    var disposable: Disposable  = Disposables.disposed()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        disposable = Single.fromCallable {
            Log.d("Trackme", "process start")
            disposable.dispose()
            (0..1000).forEach {
                if (it % 1000 == 0) Log.d("Trackme", "process $it")
            }
            throw IllegalStateException("Kill Myself")
        }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                Log.d("Trackme", "Done")
            }, {
                Log.d("Trackme", it.localizedMessage)
            })

        Log.d("Trackme", "finish subscribe")
    }
}
```

In this code, I explicitly `disposable.dispose()`, when the subscription started.
Without the `throw IllegalStateException`, it will run until finish.

```
D/Trackme: finish subscribe
D/Trackme: process start
D/Trackme: process 0
D/Trackme: process 1000
```

Nothing happens after that, which is good, as the process has been disposed.

However, if I have `throw IllegalStateException`, then it will crash, as the the Error Lambda cannot catch it anymore (since it has been disposed).

How can we capture this error?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution, which is using `RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler`, as shown below

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    var disposable: Disposable  = Disposables.disposed()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler { e -> Log.d("Trackme", "Catch App ${e.localizedMessage}") }

        disposable = Single.fromCallable {
            Log.d("Trackme", "process start")
            disposable.dispose()
            (0..1000).forEach {
                if (it % 1000 == 0) Log.d("Trackme", "process $it")
            }
            throw IllegalStateException("Kill Myself")
        }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                Log.d("Trackme", "Done")
            }, {
                Log.d("Trackme", it.localizedMessage)
            })

        Log.d("Trackme", "finish subscribe")
    }
}
```